# Collection View Selection Mechanism, Is it exists?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer, selection

Well, my `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` not being called.

I've read a lot answers, none helped me.

There is no view that takes the touch and prevents tap (I've doubled check)

---

So I started to explore:

The collection view has 3 GestureRecognizers:

1. `UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer`
2. `UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer`
3. `_UIDragAutoScrollGestureRecognizer`

As you can see, none of them is a `UITapGestureRecognizer`

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618032-collectionview?language=objc):

> The collection view calls this method when the user successfully selects an item in the collection view. It does not call this method when you programmatically set the selection.

Well, should I add a TapGesture recognizer myself? And call the delegate methods? I don't think so. Apple done something, but that something is not working!

Comment: You shouldn't need to add a tap gesture recognizer yourself and call the delegate methods manually.  You must have done something to stop the collection view to not respond to selections.  Perhaps post some more of the actual setup code so we can check.

Comment: "TapGesture recognizer myself"  As the person above says No.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth I know that I’ll post the code but you’ll see I does nothing that prevents taps on collectionView cells

Comment: Something must be preventing the selection of the collection cell.  You don't need to add your own gesture recognizers to get it to work and if you have added any the may cause issues.  All you should need to do is wire up the data source (to see the cells) and wire up the delegate (to respond to the actions).

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth I’ve already wired up the delegate and the data source, they are working perfectly, and to prove it I use the scrollViewDelegate methods of the collectionView, this works perfectly too, the collectionView scrolls and showing data, just the selection not working, I didn’t add any gesture recognizer to anything, I hope I’ll have time tomorrow to update question with relevant info and code

Comment: Ok no worries when you update the question I will take another look and see what I can find.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Thanks to you I solved it, you gave me the confidence that it's possible. I've built an example project to upload so you check it out and suddenly I got this working... The answer is below, Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out and thanks for posting the answer which can help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I got it figured out and I'm sure it will help others. Thanks for all who tried to help - you helped because I thought it's not suppose to work and you gave me the reason to keep try =]

Well I had the following hierarchy:

```
View
|
+----CollectionView
     |
     +----CollectionViewCell
          |
          +----TextView
```

The `TextView` fills the whole cell.

The problem was that the `TextView` **blocks** every tap and not forwards it to the cell!!

But it **DOES** forward other touches (like Pan)

---

> The solution is:

```
cell.textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```